# Is there a JS/jQuery plugin for sliding animations which has slideLeft & slideRight functions same as there are slideUp and slideRight functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a jQuery/JS plugin which has some functions of fading and/or sliding which has functions slideLeft & slideRight something similar to jQuery functions slideUp and slideDown. I don't want to create the functions from scratch, just want to use it straight away.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions asking for plugins recommendations are strictly off-topic here. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow.js allows you to create animations on page scroll and is very simple to use. https://wowjs.uk/